# row-fluid not splitting into half

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

'row-fluid' is not splitting to two 'span6' divs

OR

Centralised 'row-fluid' of 80% width not splitting into half with two 'span6' divs?

Rather than of 50% each 'span6' div is of 100% width and second div fall down instead of align right along with the first div. And Each div have the same width as row-fluid.

I am using bootstrap v3.3.4

Here's the code:

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid" style="background-color:#40474f; height:150px; width:80%; margin:0 auto; padding:0;">

            <div class="span6 " style="border:1px solid #f00;">
                <img class="image " src="images/logo.png" alt="placeholder image" height="119" width="542">
            </div>
            <div class="span6 " style="border:1px solid #f00;">
                <img class="image " src="images/call.png" alt="placeholder image" height="63" width="259">
             </div>

    </div>
</div>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

very simple question, but I don't know where I am mistaken on the code?
Quick solution will appreciate..

Thank you,

Comment: I suggest you read bootstrap's [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options)

Comment: In bootstrap 3, there is  `class="col-md-6"`  for half of the grid.  **Read bootstrap grid system** first.

Comment: `span6` doesn't exist with Bootstrap v3.x, this was available with v2.x! As suggested by the others, have a look at the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all those custom widths, margins, paddings and heights and replace your span6 with col-xs-6 like this:

```
<div class="row" style="background-color:#40474f;>

            <div class="col-xs-6 " style="border:1px solid #f00;">
                <img class="image img-responsive" src="images/logo.png" alt="placeholder image">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 " style="border:1px solid #f00;">
                <img class="image img-responsive" src="images/call.png" alt="placeholder image">
             </div>

</div>
```

Comment: This won't work, row-fluid is bootstrap 2 and col-xs-6 is bootstrap 3.

Comment: Also, col-xs-6 won't even wrap, it's meant to retain its position on smallest devices.

Comment: @ColeChamberlain If you use XS, it's available for higher... Not the inverse.

Comment: You sure bout that @YenneInfo? Have a look at http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/ on a phone and tell me if the col-xs-6 stack or not.

Comment: Answer updated with row-fluid replaced with just row and the widths, margins and paddings removed. container-fluid alone should do the trick.
I have also removed the specified width and height of the images and replaced them with an img-responsive class.
@ColeChamberlain "col-xs-6 won't even wrap"?? What do you mean??

Comment: @ColeChamberlain Yes I'm sure... If you are a large desktop, and make your template just with XS class, the Xs class are still there on large desktop...

Comment: The xs classes will just scale down on even very small screens, they are useful for small UIs when you don't want the columns to collapse. If you want collapsing columns you need to use col-sm, col-md, or col-lg classes.

Comment: He specified that he wanted to split the row in half which col-xs does. He never mentioned splitting it only in Desktop view so I'm just providing a way to split  the row to two columns for every screen width.

Comment: Ahh I re-read the question, I misinterpreted splitting as he wanted it to collapse. OP needs to work on his English.

Comment: I do really appreciate efforts for all you guys... Thanks again

Comment: If this answer helped you in fixing the issue, then do mark it as the right answer Rafa :)

Answer (score 0):

You're probably screwing it up by adding inline 80% styles and worse, inline html widths. That's what bootstrap is for, so you don't have that.

I'd recommend:

1. Go to bootstrap 3 as you get a lot more control with its mobile first fluid grid.
2. Get it working first without adding any of those width styles, if you want 80%, nest your rows within other rows and spans.

If you are on bootstrap 3 then simply

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6"></div>
<div class="col-md-6"></div>
</div>
```

Should suffice.